# How to retry @Scheduled task in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled, spring-retry

I have the following code sample:

```java
@Service
public class ScheduledTask {

    // Running each hour at 0 min. and 0 seconds
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * *")
    @Retryable(value = Throwable.class, maxAttempts = 2, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))
    public void execute() {
        log.info("Executing scheduled task!");
        throw new HttpTimeoutException("Let's see whether retry will rerun");
    }
}
```

I can see the task being executed once. But I do not see any retries. Is there any incompatibility between `@Scheduled` and `@Retryable` or am I missing something?

Or is there a better way to retry an `@Scheduled` task?

Comment: Have you try removing @Scheduled to verify that it is working fine in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have `@EnableRetry` annotation on your configuration class to enable the `@Retryable` annotation processing.
Same for scheduling with `@EnableScheduling`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `@EnableRetry` and `@EnableScheduling`, also make sure you have the dependency of spring-aspects (or `spring-boot-starter-aop`).