# Set the same scheduler in different pods to run in sequence, not just once

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I want the same schedules from different pods to run in sequence, not just once in multiple pods.

I have a scheduler that runs every 10 minutes and I've set Schedlock to avoid running in parallel. However, with that lib, when other pods try to run they check if it's already locked and then don't run (neither in sequence).
What I need is to have the other pods waiting 'till these same jobs are unlocked so they can run in sequence, not just running once just because the job is locked.

Ex:

```
Pod1
 Job1: Locked
Pod2:
 Job1: Don't run because are locked and finished the job
```

What I need:

```
Pod1
 Job1: Locked
Pod2:
 Job1: Wait until the job (from Pod1) are unlocked to run in sequence
```

Framework: Spring-boot
Java Version: 15

Can anyone help me in this situation?
Let me know if I wasn't clear, thanks for your attention.

Comment: does the shedlock helps in running scheduler once in the case where we have multiple instances?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to achieve this you may combine with `Spring Retry` and retry immediately after `lockAtMost` period used in Shedlock but keep in mind that this behaviour should be contained/stopped before next schedule cycle to avoid schedule conflicts.

You may refer this thread where a similar solutions without shedlock is discussed
[How to retry @Scheduled task in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67535773/how-to-retry-scheduled-task-in-spring)